# using if-else by checking page URL

Tags: javascript, url, if-statement, document.write

How can I write a function to conditionally run `document.write` depending on the current URL?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function urlCheck() {
if(
window.location.href=="address to check"
)
{
/* some code to load */
}else{
document.write('<div>testing my super loaded div code sample</div>')
}
}
urlCheck() /* autoLoadFunction */
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: "`participation is to improve functionality...`"-kind of questions should be rather posted at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> **Code Description**
>
> ***urlCheck***,
> is the name given to the function.
> you can change it, if you do, change all *urlCheck* references within the code.
>
> ***window.location.href***,
> this code returns the current address as http://...
> use to identify certain pages you want to be loaded.
> make as many if..else combinations as necessary.
>
> ***document.write***,
> build the content to be loaded first,
> and type with later in one unique line,
> or create multiple *document.write* substrings for each line of your content.